# pinch end or touch up after pinch recognition?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uigesturerecognizer

i was just searching for an appropriate event that i can catch. the pinch works well. and following line works only if there was no pinch before

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event 
{
    NSLog(@"---> event");
}
```

it seems that the pinch eats up the following touch up.

anyhow in this code the touch up is recognized

```
- (void)scalePiece:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    //[self adjustAnchorPointForGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];

    NSLog(@"scalePiece");

    if ([gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan || [gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {
        [gestureRecognizer view].transform = CGAffineTransformScale([[gestureRecognizer view] transform], [gestureRecognizer scale], [gestureRecognizer scale]);
        [gestureRecognizer setScale:1];
    }
}
```

how can i recognize the touch up of the last/second finger after pinching the view? or better said, how can i differentiate between pinch move and pinch end?

cheers

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use:

```
if ([gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
```

in your pinch function

Comment: thank you very much. it´s really a shame that i don´t see the info in the reference. it´s written in the first paragraph :-/

Comment: perhaps i´m too old for this game ;-)

Comment: thats a to simple excuse, isn't it ;) dont forget to mark as answered please